# Error running a simple hello world program C in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, error-handling, build

I am new to using C and I followed this link to set up eclipse for C
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMPMGNcDIjI

I typed in this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    printf ("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

and I hit build and I got this error message:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): in function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.2.0-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:45: TEST.exe] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

I do not know what the problem is so I don't know what I am supposed to search for.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Searching for the error message would be a good start: "undefined reference to `WinMain'"

Comment: 1) Clicky save before compiling, Eclipse is retarded. 2) Don't make a windows project, make a console project. 3) I strongly recommend to stay clear of Eclipse.

Comment: (To be clear, Eclipse is fine for Java, it's just the C support that's not that good)

Comment: Yes, it appears Eclipse has been set to compile a windows GUI program which has a WinMain function instead of main.

Comment: Eclipse is in wide use and works fine for C and C++. To save before building, just set that option in the preferences.

Comment: i dont know how to reply to comments yet im new but to whoever said i should just save it was right oh my god it worked just fine when i saved, thank you all, i also installed C for netbeans just in case i run into some problems with eclipse, again, thank you to everyone who replied :)